# PgAdmin 4 does not see default database in AWS RDS PostgreSQL

Tags: amazon-web-services, postgresql, pgadmin

I am using RDS Postgres as an analytical data warehouse and would like to connect to it via pgadmin. I was able to connect to the database, but pgadmin is not picking up my default database, i.e. the database I created (named: `anchor_reporting`) at inception of my RDS DB instance.

When I connect to my db server via psql command line tool I can see anchor_reporting and its contents. See below:

```
postgres=> \l+
                                                                                   List of databases
       Name       |      Owner      | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |          Access privileges          |   Size    | Tablespace |                Description
------------------+-----------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------------------+-----------+------------+--------------------------------------------
 anchor_reporting | reporting_admin | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/reporting_admin                 +| 9845 kB   | pg_default | default template for new databases
                  |                 |          |             |             | reporting_admin=CTc/reporting_admin |           |            |
 postgres         | reporting_admin | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |                                     | 7909 kB   | pg_default | default administrative connection database
 rdsadmin         | rdsadmin        | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | rdsadmin=CTc/rdsadmin               | No Access | pg_default |
 template0        | rdsadmin        | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/rdsadmin                        +| 7909 kB   | pg_default | unmodifiable empty database
                  |                 |          |             |             | rdsadmin=CTc/rdsadmin               |           |            |
(4 rows)
```

And if I create new database in psql I can see it in pgadmin, e.g.

```
postgres=> CREATE DATABASE testdb TEMPLATE anchor_reporting;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=> \l
                                                List of databases
       Name       |      Owner      | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |          Access privileges
------------------+-----------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------------------
 anchor_reporting | reporting_admin | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/reporting_admin                 +
                  |                 |          |             |             | reporting_admin=CTc/reporting_admin
 postgres         | reporting_admin | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 rdsadmin         | rdsadmin        | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | rdsadmin=CTc/rdsadmin
 template0        | rdsadmin        | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/rdsadmin                        +
                  |                 |          |             |             | rdsadmin=CTc/rdsadmin
 testdb           | reporting_admin | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
(5 rows)
```

View from PGAdmin4
[pgAdmin database list from RDS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJ6aD.png)

See PGAdmin4 version info below:

```
Version
4.8

Copyright
Copyright (C) 2013 - 2019, The pgAdmin Development Team

Python Version
3.7.3 (default, Apr 16 2019, 14:55:10) [Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)]

Flask Version
1.0.2

Application Mode
Desktop

Current User
pgadmin4@pgadmin.org
```

Any ideas on why this would happen?